# Prove: $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k·k!=n!−1$

Tags: combinatorics

Show: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k·k!=n!−1$$ via combinatoric proof. I know how to prove via induction but not via combinatorial method.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$k.k!=(k+1)!-k!$  and  use the telescopic sum

Comment: Unfortunately, this proof is more algebraic than combinatorial..

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be the set $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$. There are $n!-1$ permutations $\varphi$ of $S$ that move at least one of the elements of $S$, that is, such that $\varphi(x)\ne x$ for at least one $x$ in $S$. We count these permutations in another way.

For $2\le k+1\le n$, let $\Pi_k$ be the set of all permutations $\varphi$ of $S$ such that $k+1$ is the largest $x$ such that $\varphi(x)\ne x$. We count the permutations in $\Pi_k$.

There are $k$ choices for the value of $\varphi(k+1)$. For any such choice, say $l$, there are $k!$ ways that the numbers $1$ to $k$ can be mapped to the numbers from $1$ to $k+1$, with $l$ missing. It follows that $\Pi_k$ has $k\cdot k!$ elements.

Add up, $k=1$ to $k=n-1$. This gives the sum of the cardinalities of all the $\Pi_k$, which is the number of non-trivial permutations of $S$.